# How to Print list [] based JSON?

Tags: json, python-2.7, api, python-3.x, request

I am trying to print below json output using below script,

Json Sample:

```
[{"id":"56cd7e4d2d0edcace915e674","protocol":"https","hostName":"127.0.0.1","port":443,"serverName":"Site1","status":"connected","connected":true}]
```

Code i have used:

```
import Requests
response = requests.get("https://Site1/rest/settings/all-server-status",params={'serverId': '56cd7e4d2d0edcace915e674'}, verify=False)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

When i am trying to print json_data i got below error,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#116>", line 1, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Please help me on this, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your JSON object is within `list` brackets `[]`. JSON objects should just be dictionaries, between curly braces: `{}`

Comment: So, we cant do anything! Is there any other work around we can do so that we can achieve this? @katya Handler

Comment: Are you sure that `response.text` contains JSON?

Comment: Not Sure, I am just trying to get output with various syntax. If there any other syntax please suggest me. Please refer below sample JSON output `[{"id":"56cd7e4d2d0edcace915e674","protocol":"https","hostName":"127.0.0.1","port":443,"serverName":"Site1","status":"connected","connected":true}]`.

Comment: If you're not sure then why do you think you can decode anything from it?

Comment: Ok, So how can i get my output with out decode the response? How to achieve, I am so confused now!

Comment: Step 1: **Verify that your input is what you expect it to be.**

Comment: If speed isn't an issue, I always recommend reading in tricky output as strings using `readlines()`. Then, on the resulting strings. do a `replace("[{", "{")` and `replace("}]", "}")`. Then it should be in a json format.